# Acceleration of a block on a wedge, Taylor Classical Mechanics problem 7.19

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I've been struggling with this exercise (7.19 in Classical Mechanics by John Taylor) for a long time. What do they mean by "You need to find the components of this acceleration relative to the table"? Could someone help me?

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that removes the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the equations I'm assuming Example 7.5 (p. 258) describes the mass and block as moving without friction.

As $M \rightarrow 0$, the action of the wedge on the block should become negligible (intuitively, it requires an infinitesimal force to slide the block out the way as its mass tends to $0$). So the expectation in this limit is that the block falls as if the wedge wasn't there i.e. vertically downwards with acceleration $g$.

To check this expectation, the limit $M\to 0$ in (7.66) and (7.67) is taken as
$$
\ddot{q}_2 = -\frac{m}{M+m} \ddot{q}_1\cos\alpha\to-\frac{m}{0+m} \ddot{q}_1\cos\alpha=-\ddot{q}_1\cos\alpha
$$
and similarly
$$
\ddot{q}_1 \to \frac{g\sin\alpha}{1-\cos^2\alpha} = \frac{g}{\sin\alpha} \qquad (1-\cos^2\alpha=\sin^2\alpha)
$$
Substituting $\ddot{q}_1$ into $\ddot{q}_2$ gives
$$
\ddot{q}_2=-g \frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}
$$
It remains to note that the horizontal component of the blocks position relative to the table is $q_2+q_1\cos\alpha$ whilst the vertical component is simply $q_1\sin\alpha$ (taking the downwards direction as positive). Therefore the horizontal component of acceleration relative to the table vanishes:
$$
\ddot{q}_2+\ddot{q}_1\cos\alpha = -g \frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha} + \frac{g}{\sin\alpha} \cos\alpha = 0
$$
and the vertical (downwards) component
$$
\ddot{q}_1\sin\alpha= \frac{g}{\sin\alpha}\sin\alpha =g
$$
as expected.